# Difference between Jenkins Job and FreestyleJob

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Using Jenkins DSL plugin I've come across [Job](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job) and [freeStyleJob](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob). Is there any difference between the two looking at the sparse documentation they look like they are the exact same thing. Do they both exist for historical reasons or is there actually a difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same thing. The method `Job()` was introduced since version 1.30 of the [job-dsl-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) and acts as an alias for `freeStyleJob()`.

At the moment of this writing you have following methods:

```
job(String name, Closure closure = null)          // since 1.30, an alias for freeStyleJob

freeStyleJob(String name, Closure closure = null) // since 1.30

buildFlowJob(String name, Closure closure = null) // since 1.30

ivyJob(String name, Closure closure = null)       // since 1.38

matrixJob(String name, Closure closure = null)    // since 1.30

mavenJob(String name, Closure closure = null)     // since 1.30

multiJob(String name, Closure closure = null)     // since 1.30

workflowJob(String name, Closure closure = null)  // since 1.30

multibranchWorkflowJob(String name, Closure closure = null) // since 1.42
```

*https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands#job*